# Check if using Windows console in Vim while in Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Vim inside the Windows Subsystem for Linux. The windows command prompt has a bug which [renders the background color incorrectly](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/832).

The fix is `set t_ut=`. Rather than applying this fix in all situations, I assume it would make sense to only apply it when Vim is being used inside the Windows console.

Unfortunately, I am not sure how to detect whether the Windows console is being used, because I am inside the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: I dunno, maybe do something like `echo $PATH` and see if something like the string 'bin' is in there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used the following code that implemented Roadowl's comment.

```
let uname = substitute(system('uname'),'\n','','')
if uname == 'Linux'
    if system('$PATH')=~ '/mnt/c/WINDOWS'
        " We are in Windows Subsystem
    endif
endif
```

**Update**: I combined roadowl's and bk2204's answer:

```
let uname = substitute(system('uname'),'\n','','')
if uname == 'Linux'
    let lines = readfile("/proc/version")
    if lines[0] =~ "Microsoft"
        return 1
    endif
endif
```

Comment: the `system('uname')` will cause issue in powershell/gvim/cmd. suggest to using `if has('unix') | let lines = readfile("/proc/version") ... | endif`

Answer (score 8):

Typically, one addresses issues like this by detecting the terminal type, but it seems Microsoft Terminal reports `xterm-256color` when it really doesn't support this.

It's possible to detect whether one is running WSL with a function like the following:

```
function! IsWSL()
  if has("unix")
    let lines = readfile("/proc/version")
    if lines[0] =~ "Microsoft"
      return 1
    endif
  endif
  return 0
endfunction
```

This is consistent with the way that Microsoft suggests that WSL be detected.

Comment: `has('linux')` did not do anything for me

Comment: `has('unix')` works for WSL, `has('linux')` is always false

Comment: Both `has('unix')` and `has('linux')` are true for me in WSL 1. I haven't tested with WSL 2.